# Display historical characters "uͤ", "oͤ" and "aͤ"?

Tags: characters, german

I'm trying to display the above mentioned symbols. These are German historical letters which I need to mention in my thesis. I just found how to display letters with an "o" above them, but nothing with an "e". Any ideas?

Comment: You might be interested in the font [Junicode](http://junicode.sourceforge.net/), which was designed specifically for medievalists and which supports, among many others things, the superscript e as a regular feature. Note that you have to use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX in order to use Junicode and these Unicode features. Once you’ve installed the package `junicode` (which is on CTAN), you can simply use `\usepackage{fontspec} \setmainfont{Junicode}` and type in the characters as you did in your question title.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can use the great Fraktur font by Yannis Haralambous:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{yfonts}

\begin{document}

\textfrak{Clavier"ubung Clavier*ubung}

\textfrak{"a *a "o *o "u *u}

\end{document}
```

The “older” orthography with a small “e” above the vowel is obtained by prefixing the vowel with `*` instead of `"` that produces the standard *umlaut*.

[image]

The same with `\textswab` instead of `\textfrak` for the Schwabacher font.

[image]

Consult the paper by Haralambous in TUGboat: https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb12-1/tb31hara.pdf

If you want an emulation with Roman fonts, here's a possibility:

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\e}[1]{%
  \leavevmode
  \vbox{\offinterlineskip
    \check@mathfonts
    \ialign{%
      ##\cr
      \hidewidth\fontsize{\numexpr\ssf@size/2}\z@\bfseries\itshape e\hidewidth\cr
      \noalign{\kern.2ex}
      #1\cr
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\e{a} \e{o} \e{u}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the delayed answer - even though the thread is old, it is still the most pertinent answer I found. 

I have a small question: The "Roman" solution seems perfect for me, but I get an "invalid unit of measure" error everytime. Is there a fix to get rid of that? (It might make me miss more important error messages...) I assume, a part like "sff@size" or so is a unit of measure (Xe)Tex doesn't recognise?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @PaulBurgh I tried, but I got no error. Maybe you pasted just the definition, but not `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` around it?

Comment: That wasn't it. But the "fix-cm" package makes me think it might be that I am not using Computer Modern. However, I got it fixed by changing \fontsize{\numexpr\ssf@size/2} to \fontsize{4pt}. I assume this doesn't scale, but then again, it's a one-time-thing so it works well enough. Now I just need to replace all the oͤs with \e{o}. :)

Answer (score 23):

You can also have a lot of fun with OpenType Fonts. Please compare input and output. The font is [UnifrakturMaguntia](http://unifraktur.sourceforge.net/) (OFL). The font replaces all instances of umlauts to the pendant with the *e* above (`StylisticSet=15`). For capital letters we can choose to have the *e* next to the letter using `StylisticSet=14`.

`StylisticSet=11` implements a heuristics to replace the round s with the long s (ſ). As this cannot be perfect, we need to help out a bit using `\/`.

The command for emphasized text has been redefined to give letterspacer text, common for Blackletter fonts. Required ligatures are kept.

Adding the combining character is also possible for roman fonts to get umlauts with a little e above.<sup>1</sup>

[image: deborahFrakfontStyleSet]

```
% arara: xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\frakfont{UnifrakturMaguntia}
\renewcommand\emshape{\xspace\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=20.0,WordSpace=1.5,}}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[left=2cm]{geometry}
\setlength{\textwidth}{420pt}
\begin{document}
\Large
\frakfont\addfontfeature{StylisticSet={11,14,15},Ligatures=NoCommon}
Und dann hüpfte das kleine Kaninchen, dem
    Regen trotzend, über den künstlichen Rasen zur
    Sonnenfinsternis. \emph{Manche sitzen} in der Wachstube, andere
lutschen an der Wachs\/tube, andere etc.\bigbreak

Using combining diacritics is also possible, if the font supports
it:\par
uͤ Aͤ \normalfont  suͤßes Oͤsterreich
\end{document}
```

<sup>1</sup> Right now, the redefinition of `\emshape` is global and would apply to roman fonts as well. Better to use an environment to locally switch the definition of `emshape` and related stuff.

Comment: Shouldn't `si` in `sitzen` also be spaced apart? Font bug?

Comment: @Sverre No font bug, i was in a hurry writing the answer, which is to be honest, some kind of stock material http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/13007/yfonts-gibt-es-eine-tabelle-info-fuer-die-texteingabe-des-rundes-s-der-umlaute-etc Seems i have modified the example at a later point on my machine. Updated the answer :-) Thank you for noticing.

Comment: While the last line matches the output, it is probably not what you want it to be. You probably want to write `uͤ Aͤ`, so you demonstrate that you can achive the output using combining characters instead of stylistic sets.

Comment: Also note that with UnifrakturMaguntia, you usually want to use Stylistic Sets 14 and 15 together, as the former replaces *Ä, Ö, Ü* with *Ae, Oe, Ue,* which was the predominant spelling/style, when *aͤ, oͤ* and *uͤ* were used (the latter got replaced by *ä, ö* and *ü* some time before capital umlauts were invented). There are only very few historical examples of *Aͤ, Oͤ* and *Uͤ.*

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Thanks a lot, i have made some additions. If you have any good material on typesetting blackletter in english, i would like to add a link. Right now, all i have is in german.

Comment: @Johannes_B: [Here](http://unifraktur.sourceforge.net/Nightly/Documentation.pdf) is the current state of UnifrkaturMaguntia’s documentation, but it’s work in progress. As for everything else: Do you want material of typesetting blackletter for the English language or do you want material in English for typesetting blackletter?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Thanks for the edit, sounds much better now. Something to link, so i guess both. I am not even sure how to treat long and round s in english. The ligatures are treated in a special way. Stuff people should know and not simply *start*.

Comment: I cannot walk thourgh my hometown looking at the street signs, it is just depressing: *Am Marstall* or *Waiſenhauſ=straße* and similar ones that make me cry and angry.

Comment: @Johannes_B: There are some links on specific topics in the documentation. — *Stuff people should know and not simply* start. – I totally fail to understand what you are referring to.

Comment: @Johannes_B is it possible to set-up XeLatex to set all umlauts in the (fraktur) text as uͤ etc.?

Comment: @harryhaller Isn't that just what the code is doing? I don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

How about this one?

```
\font\vse=cmr10 at 5pt
\setbox0=\hbox{a}
This is a \raise\ht0\rlap{\hbox to \wd0{\hfil\vse e\hfil}}\box0 Test.
```

in plain TeXnique.
[image]