# Old diacritic: e over vowel

Tags: symbols, ligatures

For a historic text, how can I typeset a lower case e above another vowel, like e over u?

The `oldgerm` package provides that, but only for its fonts like Fraktur:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{oldgerm}
\begin{document}
\frakfamily *a *o *u      
\end{document}
```

How do I get that in a modern font like Helvetica?

Comment: The [Junicode font](http://junicode.sourceforge.net/) (a font designed for historical use) provides these as combining characters, but to do it with any arbitrary font you'd need to roll your own, perhaps using the `stackengine` package.

Comment: [Display historical characters "uͤ", "oͤ" and "aͤ"?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/250629)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple roll-your-own approach, using the standard LaTeX box making and box raising tools.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{helvet}
\newcommand\ue{\raisebox{2\height}{\makebox[0pt][l]{\kern1.3pt\tiny e}}u}
\begin{document}
\textsf{M\ue sli}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The linked solution by @egreg contains a much better implementation of this idea.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{oldgerm,stackengine,graphicx}
\newcommand\xe[1]{\stackengine{.5pt}{#1}{\scalebox{.6}{\tiny e\,\,}}{O}{r}{F}{F}{S}}
\begin{document}
\xe{a} \xe{o} \xe{u}

\frakfamily *a *o *u   
\end{document}
```

[image]

One may add an `\itshape` after the `\tiny` to get a slightly different presentation:

[image]